# 2017 Imac screen brightness after installing Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: drivers

I have just installed (July 2021) Ubuntu 64 bit 20.4 on a 2017 Intel iMac

The sound was a problem, I have resolved that.

The Screen brightness is also a problem. I can not adjust the screen brightness using the Ubuntu software

I have little to no understanding of Ubuntu and command line instructions so will need to be led.

Anyone out there can spare some time to get the problem resolved?

Comment: Sorry tto say it but you might get better mac information from this https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/112 forum. You need the Mac firmware and will need to copy some files. There is no simple fix IMHO.

Comment: It certainly seems that there is no simple answer. Thank you

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295423/ubuntu-20-04-on-imac-mid-2011-cant-adjust-brightness

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal Intel-Board inside?

I had the problem on my Intel-laptop and used this command as root (sudo -i):

```
echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

First try to find the path to the backlight-file and then try to change the backlight brightness. First reduce the number, so that you can still see something. If the screen is black (echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness), then you can not see something any more.

You can start with 1000 and then go down and decrease 100 every time, till you can see some changes.

Comment: I dont understand what you want me to do. As I said I have little experience with command line instructions and prefer not to stuff it up completely

Comment: You don't have to. Simply take a look at your Linux "explorer" ... the file-browser. In my case it is called Nautulus. Go to your root "/" and then to "/sys" ... till you seethe file "brightness". This path: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  Does it exist?

Comment: I found Nautilus and am unable to find out how to go to "Root" I took a desktop photo of what I have with the expectation that I could share that with you to give me some insight into where to go to next.
Sorry to be so bloody slow but its al new to me

Comment: This is okay, I had to figure out how it works too. Press in your filebrowser (natilus, thunar or what ever is installed on your system) "Strg + L" and then you can insert a path. Maybe "/" (= root of the system) or "/sys/class/" then you can see ... is there a folder named backlight or something what looks like the name could be related to the background light and then go into the folder and look further ... is there a folder "intel_backlight" or something similar. If this would be true, then try the command in your terminal (in Windows you would start "cmd").

Comment: Thank you. I will explore what you are telling me there and see if I can get the working.. I appreciate your help

Comment: Problem sorted, another step into the deep unknown :) . Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it work?  Or do you have installed Windows again? I wrote 4 little scripts, which I can activate with keyboard-shortcuts (brightness-plus, brightness-minus, brightness-zero, brightness-standard), so that I can change it over the keyboard easily.

Comment: It works really well... 
I will never go back to Windows... I am running Ubuntu 20.4 on a 2016 iMac. I have been unable to remove the iMac start files on one of the partitions and it slows the start procedure. I dont want to format the partition in case it holds the drivers for my iMac. As I said... Its a whole new ball game for me..

Comment: If this method works, show it to other people with a checkmark or upvote. So you can help other people with the same problem to find the right answer.