# How can i fix Brightness adjustment on iMac 11.2 under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ? The brightness still at his max

Tags: brightness, amd-graphics, grep, apple

I'm new to Linux, and I don't know much about commands, I have an iMac 11.2 Intel® Core™ i5 CPU 680 @ 3.60GHz × 4, RAM 12 gb on which I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 After solving the ventilation problem that did not stop and after installing other drivers such as the WIFI/bluetooth card, I tried everything to solve the problem of brightness but impossible. I read about fifty forums with similar problems but impossible to do as much. My brightness slide don't react. I leave you the returns of command lines I've entred to diagnose the problem.

`dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii`

```
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                                        Version                                 Architecture Description
+++-==========================================-=======================================-============-================================================================================
hi  grub-efi-amd64-signed                      1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1        amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
```

`ls -l /var/crash`

```
total 9624
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     whoopsie    5156 août  24 03:29 apple-bl-gmux-dkms.0.crash
-rw------- 1 root     whoopsie  480469 août  22 13:37 grub-efi-amd64.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie   81162 août  21 01:24 _usr_bin_clinfo.0.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     whoopsie       0 août  21 01:24 _usr_bin_clinfo.0.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 août  21 01:24 _usr_bin_clinfo.0.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 lamine   whoopsie 6082323 août  22 03:31 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 lamine   whoopsie   75559 août  21 12:06 _usr_bin_indicator-cpufreq.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lamine   whoopsie       0 août  21 03:29 _usr_bin_indicator-cpufreq.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 août  21 03:29 _usr_bin_indicator-cpufreq.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 lamine   whoopsie 2752841 août  21 01:25 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lamine   whoopsie       0 août  21 01:25 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 août  21 01:25 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 lamine   whoopsie  348831 août  22 12:29 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-messages_indicator-messages-service.1000.crash
```

`lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 '\''[030[02]\]' | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|kernel"`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M] [1002:68c0] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

`systemctl status systemd-backlight@acpi_video0.service`

```
systemd-backlight@acpi_video0.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of acpi_video0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-backlight@.service(8)
```

`lsmod | grep acpi`

```
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
```

`lsmod | grep amd`

```
$ : commande introuvable
```

(As Root Sudo -i)

`dmesg | grep -i amdgpu`

```
[   17.552271] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   17.553203] amdgpu: CRAT table not found
[   17.553214] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[   17.553262] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[   17.872326] Modules linked in: ccm amdgpu cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep iommu_v2 drm_buddy gpu_sched btusb btrtl btbcm btintel btmtk bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videodev videobuf2_common mc apple_mfi_fastcharge joydev input_leds binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core applesmc kvm radeon snd_hwdep ath9k irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul polyval_generic ath9k_common ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 drm_ttm_helper aesni_intel snd_pcm ath9k_hw ttm drm_display_helper crypto_simd cryptd ath snd_seq_midi cec rc_core intel_cstate mac80211 snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device i2c_algo_bit snd_timer at24 cfg80211 syscopyarea snd sysfillrect intel_ips sysimgblt libarc4 soundcore mac_hid apple_bl sch_fq_codel coretemp msr parport_pc ppdev
```

`sudo lshw -c video`

```
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M]
       fabricant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nom logique: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration : depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       ressources : irq:31 mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0400000-d041ffff portE/S:2000(taille=256) mémoire:d0420000-d043ffff
```

`ls /sys/class/backlight/`

```
acpi_video0
```

`glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'`

```
Device: AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.50.0 / 6.2.0-26-generic, LLVM 15.0.7) (0x68c0)
    Video memory: 512MB
    Unified memory: no
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 511 MB, largest block: 511 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 511 MB, largest block: 511 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 511 MB, largest block: 511 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 512 MB
    Total available memory: 1533 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 511 MB
    GL_AMD_pinned_memory, GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_memory_object, 
    GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_AMD_pinned_memory, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd,
```

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
That open and empty script

I also tried changing the lumnosity manually with commands like `echo 40 > /sys/class/backlightor` , `xrandr` but nothing worked. I am a novice but in my opinion the problem is the `acpi_video0` which should be either `readon_bl0` or `amd_gpux` or `apple_gMux`. I am lost if there is someone who understands something, I am happy to take his knowledge. THANK YOU.
PS: Sorry for the French on terminal returns

Comment: Does this work https://askubuntu.com/a/1295427/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi , i also tried this one but the result after reboot is worst; the brightness slide disapear and still impossible to adjust brightness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly that iMac and installed 23.04 on it just last week.

To activate the brightness controls you have to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file as outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1478635/21008) to the thread you already linked.

I'll copy paste it here:

> Open the grub file from the directory /etc/default or run the command:
>
> `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
>
> Edit the following line from:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
>
> to:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native"`
>
> Run the command:
>
> `sudo update-grub`
>
> Reboot

By the way, on Ubuntu 23.04 everything else works out of the box with the iMac11,2. (E.g. wifi, bluetooth...) So if you keep having issues and a non-LTS release is okay for you, you might want to upgrade. The only thing I didn't get working on 23.04 is wake from sleep. The screen doesn't turn back on, after the iMac went to sleep - I just disabled it. Apart from that it's a lovely machine. :) Enjoy yours!

Comment: Great work ! Now i can adjust the brightness, thank you a lot bro

Comment: Ha, glad I could help, man! Could you please mark this question as solved and feel free to give pinei an upvote [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1478635/21008) - it was all him. :) Enjoy the iMac!